# .change() deprecated doesn't works with .on()

Tags: jquery

I have a list of jQuery code which has the same event `.change()` which is now deprecated in latest jQuery. I have replaced that event with `.on()`. It works fine but the default values which needs to be hidden initially is now visible. Here is the Old and New Code. What wrong am I doing?

**Old Code**

```
    jQuery(".my_logo").change(function () {
        jQuery(".title").slideUp();
        jQuery(".logo").slideUp();
        var selected_teaser = jQuery(".my_logo option:selected").val();
        jQuery("."+selected_teaser).slideDown();
    }).change();
```

**New Code**

```
    jQuery(".my_logo").on('change',function () {
        jQuery(".title").slideUp();
        jQuery(".logo").slideUp();
        var selected_teaser = jQuery(".my_logo option:selected").val();
        jQuery("."+selected_teaser).slideDown();
    });
```

**Note**: If I don't remove the `change()` from the last in the New Code then it works.

Comment: could you create a small example, or include the relevant html and elaborate on "default value"?

Comment: *which is now deprecated* - can you provide a source for this?  It's not mentioned on the [jquery page](https://api.jquery.com/change/) or jquery deprecated lists (from 3.0-3.5).  There was some talk of removing `.click` and other "shortcuts" for `.on("event"` some years ago, but it was determined there were too many sites using these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to initially trigger the change - so just add an inital trigger to your eventlistener:

```js
jQuery(".my_logo")
  .on('change',function () {
        jQuery(".title").slideUp();
        jQuery(".logo").slideUp();
        var selected_teaser = jQuery(".my_logo option:selected").val();
        jQuery("."+selected_teaser).slideDown();
    })
  .trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh ya, you are right. I missed. Strange. Thank you @davidgiesemann